# Round ends for dashes

Tags: plotting

I made use of

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]},PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteDashing[10, 2],AbsoluteThickness[3],   CapForm[Round]]]
```

Then I can have

[image]

It drives me crazy when I see the end of dashes is not round as I expected from `CapForm[Round]` which is implemented in the above code. How can I have round ends?

Comment: See the 4th paradigm at the top of the doc page for `AbsoluteDashing[]`: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteDashing.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `AbsoluteDashing[10, Automatic, CapForm["Round"]]`
- `AbsoluteDashing[10, 0, CapForm["Round"]`
- `AbsoluteDashing[{10, 14}, 0, CapForm["Round"]]`
- `AbsoluteDashing[{10, 14}, Automatic, CapForm["Round"]]`
- etc.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Directive[AbsoluteDashing[10, Automatic, CapForm["Round"]], 
   AbsoluteThickness[5]]]
```

[image]